# Disable Logging on Load Balancer on Google CLoud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Logs from load balancing seem to be accumulating small costs each day for my project, so I'd like to disable the logs as I do not use them.

Following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/networklb-monitoring?utm_source=cloud_console&utm_medium=release_notes&utm_campaign=81c980e789fac29bc69796b7c5f3e4ff#disable_logging_on_an_existing_backend_service) provided by Google, I have navigated to my backend configuration (a backend bucket with Cloud CDN) - but there is no "Enable Logging" section as described in the guide.

How can I disable logs for my load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I could not find a way to disable logging, it turns out you can create a "Log Sink" to stop ingesting & storing these logs + therefore preventing the charges.

Answer (score 1):

Upon replicating this concern, I also observe that there is no option on how to enable or disable the logs in backend buckets. Regarding on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#logging_for_backend_buckets) logs are automatically enabled for load balancers with backend buckets. It was also mentioned from the documentation that you cannot disable the logs in backend buckets.

However, you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) for this kind feature that may come useful to other users.